# Python tuples manipulation

Tags: python, django, tuples

I have a tuple in Python like this -

```
a = ((-,-,x), (-,-,x), (-,-,y), (-,-,z), (-,-,z), (-,-,z))
```

Now, I want to group the tuples with the same third element. I have to convert this tuple,a into

```
b = (((-,-,x), (-,-,x)), ((-,-,y)), ((-,-,z), (-,-,z), (-,-,z)))
```

How do I write Python code for this? To convert `a` into `b`? Since tuples are immutable I'm not able to write the code successfully.

Comment: - is string or?

Comment: I don't get why tuples immutability is a problem. You here construct a *new* tuple.

Comment: I had to add so many `'` :( - next time please post data structures that we can copy-paste into the Python interpreter.

Comment: @DejanMarić '-' can be any datatype. I just wanted the logic irrespective of datatype.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, while constructing new tuple I can't give a[i] = ...

Comment: @timgeb Alright noted, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: @KeerthanBhat: in declarative programming `a[i] = ...` is frequently seen as an "antipattern".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, okay. Noted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> a = (('-','-','x'), ('-','-','x'), ('-','-','y'), ('-','-','z'), ('-','-','z'), ('-','-','z'))
>>> tuple(tuple(grp) for _, grp in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(-1)))
>>> 
((('-', '-', 'x'), ('-', '-', 'x')),
 (('-', '-', 'y'),),
 (('-', '-', 'z'), ('-', '-', 'z'), ('-', '-', 'z')))
```

It's assumed that groups of equal last elements cannot be interrupted (like in your sample data). If they can, you need to sort `a` with `key=itemgetter(-1)` first.

> ...can you explain "interrupted"?

Sure. What I mean is that `groupby` lumps together groups of **consecutive** elements where `key` returns the same value. So if we had something like

```
b = (('-','-','z'), ('-', '-', 'x'), ('-','-','z'))
```

then the `groupby` from above would create three groups, not two.

```
>>> b = (('-','-','z'), ('-', '-', 'x'), ('-','-','z'))
>>> tuple(tuple(grp) for _, grp in groupby(b, key=itemgetter(-1)))
>>> ((('-', '-', 'z'),), (('-', '-', 'x'),), (('-', '-', 'z'),))
```

If you don't want that to happen, sort `b` first.

```
>>> last = itemgetter(-1)
>>> tuple(tuple(grp) for _, grp in groupby(sorted(b, key=last), key=last))
>>> ((('-', '-', 'x'),), (('-', '-', 'z'), ('-', '-', 'z')))
```

Comment: ...can you explain "interrupted"?

Comment: Yep, OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = (('-','-','x'), ('-','-','x'), ('-','-','y'), ('-','-','z'), ('-','-','z'), ('-','-','z'))

print(tuple(tuple(x) for _, x in groupby(a)))
# ((('-', '-', 'x'), ('-', '-', 'x')), (('-', '-', 'y'),), (('-', '-', 'z'), ('-', '-', 'z'), ('-', '-', 'z')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the elements are already ordered by the last element (well the tuples with `x` as last element, etc. are positioned in a sequence), we can use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

b = tuple(tuple(vs) for _, vs in groupby(a, itemgetter(-1)))
```